# How can I make 'microphone input' for mfcc(librosa) in python?

Tags: python, librosa

I want to do this:

1. record
2. export it to mfcc display

Here is what I made, but it doesn't work:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd

print('start speaking')

Fs = 16000;
d = 3;

a = sd.rec(int(d*Fs), Fs, 1,blocking=True)

signal, sr = librosa.load(a)


mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=signal, n_mfcc=13, sr=sr)

mfccs.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
librosa.display.specshow(mfccs,
                         x_axis="time",
                         sr=sr)
plt.colorbar(format="%+2.f")
plt.show()
```

Comment: You want to record for a fixed duration, then show this (no need to have it continious)?

Comment: In what way does the code you have "not work" ?